# Windows Server 2008r2 clonezilla image cannot boot with XenServer

Tags: windows, xenserver, restore, clonezilla

I'm trying to do a P2V using clonezilla but the cloned image would not boot.

I have an IBM x3400 m3 machine running Windows Server 2008r2 as the OS. I'm turning the physical machine into a XenServer, so I tried to do a cold clone of the Windows Server 2008r2 server os (running on raid 1 SATA) using CloneZilla.

Next, I tried to set up a VM in XenServer and restore the image using CloneZilla, which was successful, but upon booting, the windows server os VM failed to boot.

I've tried to insert Windows Server 2008 R2 dvd and boot from dvd-rom and tried to do a repair but it was not successful.

My questions are:

1. What should I do in the above scenario? I am unable to boot from the old disks because they were destroyed and only the clonezilla image is available.
2. Is this a problem with the MBR and how can I fix this?
3. Is it possible to turn the clonezilla image to a VHD to import to
   XenServer?

Thank You.

Comment: Please be more specific about the "image would not boot." What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I would restore the image to the physical server direct as your image is not ready to be imported in xenserver.

To make the image after please use xenconvert from citrix, its done to migrate to xenserver, unlike the tool you used

Comment: I would have used XenConvert but it is no longer available.